# Adding certain # of hours to JS moment object

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, momentjs, utc

my app stores UTC timestamps representing some date. For example, timestamp 1541638800 represents Thursday Nov 8, 2018 at 1AM UTC time.

I need to somehow determine the number of hours in the day that are represented by the timestamp (in the example given, 1 hour into the day). Then I need to apply this to today’s date, which I was representing as a JS moment, i.e. `moment().utc().startOf('day').unix()`.

Overall asking:

1. How I can get the number of hours into the day from the UTC timestamp? Tried using the `Date` object and `getHours()`, , but it returned 17 which is incorrect.
2. How I can add these hours to a moment object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with _"How I can add these hours to a moment object?"_? Are you looking for momentjs [`add`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)?

Answer (score 0):

in moment lib you need use method .hours(), and don't forget parse your data like UTC ;

```
moment.utc(data).hours();
```

in simple JS:

Just get diff between today and today with set zero hours

```js
let nowDate = new Date();

console.log((nowDate.setMilliseconds(0) - nowDate.setHours(0)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
```

Comment: Hmm but the original date I'm trying to get the hours from is a date in the past, not necessarily today. Would this solution still work?

Comment: try .hours(); this method can give you hours; finaly solution moment.utc(oldData).hours();

Answer (score 0):

> 1541638800 represents Thursday Nov 8, 2018 at 1AM UTC

So the timestamp is seconds since the ECMAScript epoch of 1970-01-01 UTC.

The *Date* constructor takes a numeric value that is milliseconds since the epoch, so you have to multiply it by 1,000. To get the number of UTC hours into the day, use *getUTCHours*.

If you then want to set the UTC hours for the current day to the same value, use *setUTCHours*, e.g.

```js
var value = 1541638800;
var utcHr = new Date(value * 1e3).getUTCHours();
var d = new Date();
d.setUTCHours(utcHr, 0,0,0);
console.log(d.toISOString());
```

Or using moment.js:

```js
// Create a date using seconds time value
var d = moment.unix(1541638800);
// Set date to use UTC, not local
d.utc();
// Create a date for today
var m = moment();
// Set to UTC
m.utc();
// Set hour to same hours as d, zero minutes, etc.
m.hour(d.hour()).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0);

console.log(m);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

moment.js has methods for *hour* and *hours*, *minute* and *minutes*, etc. that are the same as each other.

You can also get the hour using plain mathematics, given that there are exactly 8.64e4 seconds in an ECMAScript UTC day:

```js
var value = 1541638800
// Round down to UTC hour
var utcHr = (1541638800 % 8.64e4) / 3.6e3 | 0;
var d = new Date();
d.setUTCHours(utcHr, 0,0,0);
console.log(d.toISOString());
```